# Diagnosing Slow Boot - 15.04

Tags: boot, drivers, usb, 15.04

I've recently thrown Ubuntu onto my main rig as a dual boot. I've been having an issue with a rather slow (relatively speaking) boot time. It takes around forty seconds. I seem to have found the issue, but I'm not really sure how to approach fixing it. When I run

```
    dmesg
```

I get the following:

```
[    2.482055] Switched to clocksource tsc
[   11.278410] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0002: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
[   11.278446] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0002: timeout initializing reports
[   11.278644] input: Corsair Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/0003:1B1C:1B11.0002/input/input8
[   11.334075] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0002: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard ] on usb-0000:03:00.0-2/input1
[   21.334396] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0003: timeout initializing reports
[   21.334535] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0003: hiddev0,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Device [Corsair Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard ] on usb-0000:03:00.0-2/input2
[   31.334376] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0004: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
[   31.334411] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0004: timeout initializing reports
[   31.334548] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0004: hiddev0,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Device [Corsair Corsair K95 RGB Gaming Keyboard ] on usb-0000:03:00.0-2/input3
```

Full results here
http://pastebin.com/7wbT8iW6

I ran across an unofficial driver for this keyboard. I've already updated the kernel to 4.0.4-040004-generic in an attempt to fix things. This resulted in no change. Would installing that driver be a potential fix? Is there some other solution I should look into? Thank you for the help.

Comment: For the record these lines are implicated, and I run into the same issue on 15.10 with my Corsair K70 keyboard:

  [   11.278410] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0002: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
  ...
  [   21.334396] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0003: timeout initializing reports

Comment: It seems likely that the unofficial driver mentioned is https://github.com/ccMSC/ckb. It's README has a list of usbhid.quirks to try for the various device models it supports.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER**: I am a green Linux user, the information I present here is taken from a similar problem and resolution in another forum.  I have also applied these steps to my own machine and verified that it works on my machine.  I do not endorse this as a generally accepted solution for all variants of this scenario.  This is a "works for me" solution I present and I realize that it *may* also work for others.  I would definitely familiarize yourself with [grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) before proceeding.

### The Problem

The problem as noted is implicated in the following dmesg lines:

---

```
[ 11.278410] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0002: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
...
[ 21.334396] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B11.0003: timeout initializing reports
```

---

This is adding about 30 seconds to your boot-up time.  The device it is complaining about isn't the actual keyboard controller, rather, it's the keyboard LED back-light controller (which technically isn't a keyboard) and doesn't know what to do with it.  If your keyboard is like mine (I have the K70) then it has two USB cables, one for the back-light and the other for the keyboard.

### Solution - Add USB HID Probing Quirks for the Kernel

Run the following command from terminal:

```
lsusb | grep -i '1B1C:1B11'
```

To verify that the device that `dmesg` complains about is in-fact your *Corsair K95 Keyboard*.  Alternatively you can run `lsusb -v | less` and visually confirm that the report descriptors are unavailable for this device.

Add the following flag to your `grub2` configuration:

```
usbhid.quirks=0x1b1c:0x1b11:0x20000000
```

**NOTE**: The `0x1b1c:0x1b11` corresponds to your back-light controller verified using `lsusb` and reported in `dmesg`.

**NOTE**: The `0x` prefix is important, without this prefix the parser will fail.

The simplest way to do this is to edit your `/etc/default/grub` file and add it to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable.  This is what mine looks like for my *Corsair K70 Keyboard* (**do not simply copy/paste this** as yours is likely different!):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbhid.quirks=0x1b1c:0x1b13:0x20000000"
```

Save your changes and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now reboot your machine and you will experience a faster boot to login time.

Comment: For future users:

I had to add the following, for it to work: usbhid.quirks=0x1b1c:0x1b13:0x20000000

Comment: Confirmed, I stumbled upon this independently and found the code that parses this uses `sscanf` with the format `"0x%hx:0x%hx:0x%x"`